# What code creates the selenium error “WebDriverException: Message: TypeError: rootNode is null”?

Tags: selenium, geckodriver

In this question I am *not* asking to help solve this problem (that would be too much asked). I am asking where I can find the code that actually generated that error message.

The error massage occurs when running with a firefox webdriver with python-selenium.

As far as I know the first part

```
WebDriverException: Message:
```

is generated by selenium itself. But where does the other part come from?

```
TypeError: rootNode is null
```

Is it from firefox itself? geckodriver? Marionette? Something else?

What source code do I need to check to find the following character string?

```
TypeError: rootNode is null
```

Full stacktrace:

```
  ...
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 934, in save_screenshot
    return self.get_screenshot_as_file(filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 911, in get_screenshot_as_file
    png = self.get_screenshot_as_png()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 943, in get_screenshot_as_png
    return base64.b64decode(self.get_screenshot_as_base64().encode('ascii'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 953, in get_screenshot_as_base64
    return self.execute(Command.SCREENSHOT)['value']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 311, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 237, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
WebDriverException: Message: TypeError: rootNode is null
```

Software used:

- Firefox: Mozilla Firefox 57.0.3
- geckodriver: 0.19.1
- nosetests: version 1.3.7
- selenium: 3.8.0

Comment: What is the full stack trace? on what code do you get the exception?

Comment: You haven't mentioned the _Selenium Client_ variant. Each _Selenium Client_ might be having different code base.

Comment: @DebanjanB: Its python. I have updated the question

Comment: Its probably a mismatch between versions. Try updating `geckodriver` to the newest version.

Comment: @Guy: No an answer to my question. I did not ask how to fix it. I ask where the error test is coming from...

Comment: @Alex That's why I wrote a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Guy: Ok, then thanks for that. But the geckodriver is at the latest version (I will update the incorrect info in the question)'

Comment: I have asked the same question here with stack trace info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57949563/typeerror-rootnode-is-null-happens-when-taking-screenshots-using-selenium-fra