# "TypeError: rootNode is null" happens when taking screenshots using Selenium framework

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, geb

Why this error `TypeError: rootNode is null` happens when taking screenshots? Is there a problem in HTML DOM structure which the developer should fix or is it a problem with Selenium version?

This error is happening when taking screenshot:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: TypeError: rootNode is null
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'linuxhost', ip: 'x.x.x.x', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '2.6.32-754.17.1.el6.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_202'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 60.8.0, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:headless: false, moz:processID: 6651, moz:profile: /tmp/rust_mozprofile.LlBKoU..., moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin: false, moz:webdriverClick: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: LINUX, platformName: LINUX, platformVersion: 2.6.32-754.17.1.el6.x86_64, rotatable: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}}
Session ID: 1afd06ed-4939-42c9-9d1d-51fa113dfe97
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:609)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.getScreenshotAs(RemoteWebDriver.java:295)
```

dependency version:

Firefox: Mozilla Firefox 60.8.0
geckodriver: 0.23.0
selenium: 3.141.59
geb-spock:3.0.1

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried and it worked for me.

- Firefox : 69.0 (64-bit)
- Gecko Driver: v0.25.0
- Webdriver: 3.141.59

```java
FirefoxDriver fdriver;
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/path/geckodriver");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);

FirefoxOptions foptions = new FirefoxOptions();
foptions.merge(capabilities);
fdriver = new FirefoxDriver(foptions);
fdriver.get("http://demo.guru99.com/selenium/guru99home/");

File src = ((TakesScreenshot) fdriver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
try {
    // now copy the screenshot to desired location using copyFile //method
    FileUtils.copyFile(src, new File("path/fchart.png"));
    fdriver.quit();
}
catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out why "TypeError: rootNode is null" error is happening.

This error happens if test is trying to taking screenshot before even the html page source is completely downloaded.

Adding a dynamic wait to wait for page to load completely did fixed this issue.

```
  waitFor {
         ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete")
      }

takeScreenshot()
```